# Azure web-app has status "AdminDisabled"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Hy, I changed my abonnement from my 170$ voucher to usage paying after it was disabled. Now my web-apps/api-apps have a "AdminDisabled" status. Now I don't know how to reactivate them to get them back online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a ticket and they will solve it for you:
https://portal.azure.com/?#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade